# crear directorio desde linea de comndos

Tags: bash

Recientemente en un urso de docker halle el siguiente comando

```
[ ! -d 'CC201' ] && git clone https://github.com/ibm-developer-skills-network/CC201.git
```

que al parecer crea un directorio, pero no entiendo... ?que significa el `!`?.

Entiendo que los corchetes solo sirven solamente para agrupar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según [la documentación](https://devdocs.io/bash/):

- `[ ... ]` Alias para `test`: Evalúa una expresión condicional y retorna 0 (true) o 1(false).

  - `!` Como argumento de `test`, niega el resultado de la evaluación
  - `-d` Como argumento de `test`, comprueba si el nombre indicado es un directorio.
- `cmd1 && cmd2`: el `cmd2` se ejecuta si, y solo si, el `cmd1` retorno `0` (true).

Todo junto, puede leerse como

> Comprueba si `CC201` **no** es un directorio, en cuyo caso ejecuta la orden `git ...`

Answer (score 1):

De hecho los corchetes son un equivalente al comando test. Y dentro de este, la opción -d comprueba si existe el fichero o directorio. Y el ! lo está negando.

Es decir que vendría a decir:

Si no existe CC201 entonces ejecuta el git clone ...

Más info con el man de test